# Github API - Adding a collaborator with Read permissions

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using the Github API (v3) collaborators endpoint to add a collaborator.

I only request `pull` permission, but yet the collaborators keep getting added with "Write" access instead of "Read" access

Shouldn't the permissions correspond as follows?

```
pull: read
push: write
admin: admin
```

Here's the code I'm using in Django

```
    # Add the person as a collaborator
    r = requests.put(
        'https://api.github.com/repos/' + \
        github_repository['owner']['login'] + \
        '/' + \
        github_repository['name'] + \
        '/collaborators/' + \
        github_username,
        params = {
            'permission': 'pull',
        },
        auth = [ ...auth... ],
    )
```

This is the documentation for the endpoint in question: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator

Comment: Just because your collaborators have write access does not mean that they should have write access to _every branch_.  You should protect critical branches by preventing direct push access to them.  Instead, only allow collaborators to create pull requests to those branches, which only an admin can complete.

Comment: Are you adding them to a personal repository or organization?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the comment. For our current use case, we only ever use master.

Comment: @osowskit organization